# How to change in gvim GTK file browser the default file mask wildcard (glob)?

Tags: gvim, linux, options, filetype-c++, load

In gvim the command `:browse confirm e` launches a GTK file browser. The default file mask in this window depends on the filetype from which the browse window is invoked. I would like to change that default file mask depending on the filetype. For example from `.cpp` file the mask is `*.cpp *.c++` and I want to add `*.hpp *.ipp` there. From python file the mask is `*.py` I would like it to be `*`. And so on.

I use gvim version 8.1.141 on linux devuan beowulf.

[image: The GTK browser invoked by gvim]

(I could not find proper tags for this question, I tried to use tags: file browser, gtk, wildcard, glob, mask)

So far by grepping gvim sources I have found:

```sh
grep -E "\*\.cpp \*\.c++" . -r --color

./runtime/ftplugin/pyrex.vim:                   \ "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n" .
./runtime/ftplugin/c.vim:    let b:browsefilter = "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n" .
./runtime/ftplugin/c.vim:         \ "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n" .
```

So what is `b:browsefilter` and how to use it?

The `:h browsefilter` says that "You can override the filter setting on a per-buffer basis by setting the b:browsefilter variable.".

But I want to override it not per-buffer, but per-filetype from where the browse dialog was invoked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is about vi/vim, not the GTK file browser.

Comment: Well, the glob information is passed on from `gvim`. How else the browser would know which buffer inside gvim was active upon invocation? I am thinking about grepping gvim sources to find the variable name for that. Was hoping that someone knows it. OK, so far I got this: `grep -E "\*\.cpp \*\.c\+\+" . -r --color` yields: `./runtime/ftplugin/c.vim:    let b:browsefilter = "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n"`. So what is `b:browsefilter` and how to use it ?

Comment: ah interesting; didnt know that. Your best first stop is always `:help browsefilter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browsefilter variable is a convenient way to add custom glob like filters for the graphical `:browse` dialog and select only the relevant filetypes for display.

As you discovered, those are usually set in the filetype plugins. If you want to customize those filters, create a file in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` (replace `<filetype>` by the wanted filetype, e.g. `c` and `python`) and add the following content (this example is for your c filetype):

```
if exists("b:browsefilter")
    let b:browsefilter = "My C Source Files (cpp,c++,hpp,ipp)\t*.cpp;*.c++;*.hpp;*.ipp\n". b:browsefilter
endif
```

It is important to place this in the `after` directory, as the default filetype needs to be run first to initialize the `b:browsefilter` variable that you can than customize further.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. A bonus question: how can I tell a running gvim session to reload `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` ? Ah OK `:source ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` worked :)