# GVim on Windows 7 - open file sets default suffix, want all suffixes

Tags: gvim, open

In GVim running on Windows 10, when I open a file, the displayed files are limited to the suffix of the file currently being editted, e.g., "C Source Files (*.c)". I can change the pull down to "All Files (*.*)" but this is cumbersome.

In particular I edit Verilog (*.v) and System Verilog (*.sv). I'd like to skip the step where I have to select from the pull down to All Files. It's rather cumbersome.

The Mac version of GVim (mvim) shows all files and doesn't try to "help" you.

Any ideas?

[Edit]
Thanks for the comments.  Adding the following in _gvimrc works.
let b:browsefilter = "All files (*.*)\t*.*\n"

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Take a look at this question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22905/18609. It's not on Windows, but it seems to match what you're seeing.

Comment: try emptying the `b:browsefilter` variable

Comment: @Guddo Please post that as an answer, instead of an edit to your question... Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe @ChristianBrabandt would like to post it as an answer, since his comment led to the solution of the problem...

Comment: @filbranden okay, done

Comment: @Guddo Your last edit is not really part of the question. If you think it's different enough from the posted answer, then perhaps post what worked for you as an answer. If you think the posted answer solved your problem, then please accept it. Also feel free to post a comment on the posted answer if you think it helped you but missed some detail, and perhaps including that detail would have improved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When using the graphical versions of the open dialog (e.g. using `:browse :e` command), vim will try to be clever and apply a filetype filter depending on your current filetype. So for a C file, it provides filter to only show C source files (`*.c, *.cpp`) , or header files (`*.h`) or a couple of other ones.

What Vim considers to be grouped together and shown to you in that dialog, can be customized by the [browsefilter](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#browsefilter) variable:

> For MS Windows and GTK, you can modify the filters that are used in
> the browse dialog.  By setting the g:browsefilter or b:browsefilter
> variables, you can change the filters globally or locally to the
> buffer.  The variable is set to a string in the format "{filter
> label}\t{pattern};{pattern}\n" where {filter label} is the text that
> appears in the "Files of Type" comboBox, and {pattern} is the pattern
> which filters the filenames.  Several patterns can be given, separated
> by ';'.

If you want to disable this behavior, you can just empty the buffer-local variable `b:browsefilter`:

```
:unlet! b:browsefilter
```

This could be done in an after-filetype plugin, e.g. for C filetype, add this line to a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` (create non-existing directories). See e.g. [:h ftplugin-overrule](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule), if you only want this for very few specific filetypes. If you want to globally disable it, you could use e.g. an `BufEnter` autocommand (or similar ones).